# How to watch when object has a new property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Simple question : is it possible to watch when an object as a new property ?

In the JSFiddle I only initialize the property "show" of the first item in the list".
When I click on "Toggle" for first item it works.

But for the others items (that get "show" property dynamically) and for myObject (that get "test2" property dynamically) it is refresh only when you toggle the first item of the list !

In my case I want that the toggle works immediately.

Someone has an explanation ?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function()  {
    return {
     myObject: { test: 'test' },
      list: [{
        value: 1,
        show: true
      }, {
        value: 2
      }, {
        value: 3
      }, {
        value: 4
      }, {
        value: 5
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleItem: function( item ) {
     if( !item.show ) item.show = true;
     else item.show = !item.show;
      console.log(item.show)
      this.myObject.test2 = 'test2';
    }
  },
  watch: {
   list: function( newValue ) {
     console.log('NEW VALUE: ', newValue );
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
{{ myObject }}
  <div v-for="item in list">
    <span v-if="item.show">
      {{ item.value }}
    </span>
    <button @click="toggleItem(item)" type="button">Toggle !</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what you need is to use Vue.set: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: Excellent thanks you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To help Vue pick up new properties, you have to use `Vue.set()` / `this.$set` to add them. Otherwise, Vue can't detect the addition and the new property will not be reactive.

```
if( !item.show ) this.$set(item, 'show', true)
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Generally, We strongly advise to set all properties beforehand in `data()`